# how to check my application running in memory or not?

Tags: android

i want to check if my application "ABC" is currently running in my phone memory or not

any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With you phone connected to your computer, 
you can open "adb shell" in the adb tools. 
Then you will enter the linux shell of the phone. 
Inside, you can type "top" to check the processes.

Jeanno

Comment: actually in a background service i want to check my application is running or not?

Comment: I don't quite get you. Do you mean your application is a background service? No matter what your application is, it is quite hard to tell whether it's running or not. But if you insist to check it this way, you may use the notification.
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers

Comment: no my dear you still did not get i have created a background service inside my application if we start another application after running our application it is minimized right? i want check if my application is running in minimized mode in memory and such a functionality i want to achieve in a background service.